# Scala - Is there a function to map Seq[A] => Seq[Either[Throwable, B]]?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, map-function, either

I am looking for a function that will map over a collection `coll: Seq[A]` while applying a function `f: A => B` and returning a `Seq[Either[Throwable, B]]` so that errors can be handled downstream.

Is there a function similar to this that is pre-baked into some library? Perhaps Cats or Scalaz?

See my implementation below:

```
import cats.syntax.either._

def eitherMap[A,B](f: A => B, coll: Seq[A]): Seq[Either[Throwable, B]] = {
  coll.map { elem => 
      Either.catchNonFatal(f(elem))
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `Either`? It looks like `Try` would do it: `coll.map(a  => Try(f(a)))`

Comment: If you _really_ need `Either`: `coll.map(a => Try(f(a)).toEither)`

Comment: Such function would seem too specific for me. Btw, it feels a bit weird to see a signature that takes `A => B` and then somehow magically that turns into an Either in the response. I'd rather take `A => Either[Throwable, B]]` as a parameter and I'd pass `f andThen Either.catchNonFatal` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh): `coll.map(a => Try(f(a)).toEither)` seems to be the simplest/cleanest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe what you're looking for already exists exactly... But here is a generic implementation that does what you want and perhaps further reading of the [ApplicativeError](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/ApplicativeError.scala) type class in cats will give you something closer

```
type ErrorOr[A] = Either[Throwable, A]

object MapAttempt {
  implicit class MapAttemptOps[A, F[_] : Functor](fa: F[A]) {
    def mapAttempt[B, G[_]](f: A => B)(implicit appErr: ApplicativeError[G, Throwable]): F[G[B]] =
      fa.map(a => appErr.catchNonFatal(f(a)))
  }
}

import MapAttempt._

List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4).mapAttempt[Int, ErrorOr](5 / _)
```

Returns:

> res0: List[ErrorOr[Int]] = List(Left(java.lang.ArithmeticException: /
>   by zero), Right(5), Right(2), Right(1), Right(1))

Edit: The separation of trait and syntax isn't necessary so I removed it

Comment: `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4).map(n => util.Try(5/n).toEither)`